# Deploy multiple spartacus storefronts?

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud, spartacus-storefront

Is it possible to deploy multiple spartacus angular projects on Commerce Cloud?

I have two Spartacus project and want them both accessible to users. However currently they are deployed to the root and the second one overwrites the first.

Answer (score 0):

This SAP support article has the answers: https://help.sap.com/docs/SAP_COMMERCE_CLOUD_PUBLIC_CLOUD/b2f400d4c0414461a4bb7e115dccd779/1c26045800fa4f85a9d49e5a614e5c22.html?version=v2105

You just need to make sure that you match the manifest.json app name with the output in angular.json outputPath, then you can set the routing in CCV2 by setting properties as followed:

Configure all endpoints to point to the JS Storefront service.

[www.brand1.com](http://www.brand1.com) → Javascript Storefront

[www.brand2.com](http://www.brand2.com) → Javascript Storefront

Configure endpoint-to-storefront mapping in JavaScript storefront service properties.

In the Cloud Portal, choose your environment, then select Service Configuration  View configurations  JavaScript storefront.

Add your properties in the following format: jsapps..severname.=.

For example:

jsapps.app1.servername.1=www.brand1.de

jsapps.app2.servername.0=www.brand2.com